# Python - How to declare when an instance is True or False

Tags: python-3.x

I'm overwriting the MutableSet from collections.abc, and I want to be able to determine whenever its instance equates to True/False.

I know about the magic methods for comparisons, but I am looking for behaviour like checking an empty set/list that Python provides.

```py
class Example():
    pass

e = Example()

if e:
    print("This shall work - the default of an instance is True")

# What I'd like is something similar to...

if []:
    pass
else:
    print("This shall be false because it's empty, there wasn't a comparison")
```

I've looked in the cookbook: [Special methods](https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names) [Data model](https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/datamodel.html) - [Other various websites](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/python/magic-methods-in-python) - I can't seem to find the answer :(

Ultimately I would like to be able to go:

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self, value: int):
        self.value = value

    def __cool_equality_method__(self):
        return self.value > 5

a = A(10)
b = A(3)

if a:
    print("This happens")
if b:
    print("This doesn't happen")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement the `__bool__` method on your class, which is simply your old `__cool_equality_method__` renamed to `__bool__`:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, value: int):
        self.value = value

    def __bool__(self):
        return self.value > 5

a = A(10)
b = A(3)

if a:
    print("This happens")
if b:
    print("This doesn't happen")

"""
This happens
"""
```

Answer (score 2):

What about `__bool__` simply?

```
class A:
    def __bool__(self):
        if not getattr(self, 'trueish', None):
            return False
        else:
            return True

a = A()
if a:
    print("Hello")
a.trueish = True
if a:
    print("a is True")
```